# whats the difference between inclusion of null character and exclusion in character array?

Tags: c, string, character

What's the difference between the following two character arrays: one with a null character and one without a null character?

```
char name1[] = {'j','o','h','n'};
char name2[] = {'j','o','h','n','\0'};
```

If there is a difference between `name1` and `name2` how does `strlen` work on `name1` since it has no null character?

What would the result be for

```
printf("%d", name1[5] == '\0');
```

I expected it to be 0 but got 1

Comment: In both cases you define an array of `char`. If you want the `nul` terminator to be added by the compiler, you need to define the value with a string literal, for example `char name1[] = "john";`

Comment: Hm, a bit of lecture on `strlen` would probably have shown that `strlen` does **not** work on strings that aren't null-terminated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how does strlen work on name1 since it has no null character.

It doesn't. This would invoke undefined behaviour.

> I expected it to be 0 but got 1

Your code snippet tries to access `name1[5]`. Given that `name` is a `char` array of size 4, you are accessing memory that has nothing to do with that array. Possibly at the time of execution that memory happened to contain a null character, leading to this result. This cannot be predicted however, and so the behaviour is *undefined*.

Answer (score 2):

`name1` doesn't define a C-string, but `name2` does.

A C-string is a sequence of chars with the last one being the NUL char. C-string is not a type, you don't have string type in C; but the standard defines the concept of C-string. `strlen` should be used on C-string.

You defined arrays of chars. That is a type in C: a sequence of chars. Then some arrays of chars contains C-string, some others does not. `strlen` should not be used on arrays of chars that do not contain C-string.

`name1[5]` doesn't exists, that array contains only 5 chars (0 to 4).

Answer (score 1):

the differences between the first and second arrays?

1) the first array is 4 characters while the second array is 5 characters

2) cannot use functions like `strlen(),`strcpy()`,`strcmp()` on the first array, but can use those functions on the second array

Answer (score 0):

size of `name1` is not the size of `name2`
size of `name1` is 4
size of `name2` is 5
It knows from array 
Someone forgot to count from `0` not `1` when addressing an array.  That is always annoying.
`name1[5]` points to a forbidden memory address.  This is what is called a buffer overflow.

Comment: Indeed both `name1[5]` and `name2[5]` are indexing out of range.